# How to find what forms are using a Save Action

Tags: sitecore-forms

We are re-doing some backend logic for a save action we created and I need to find all forms that use this one save action. How can I easily do that? I didn't see a way in Admin interface and I don't see how to query from SQL database.

Answer (score 1):

Locate the Save Action in the content tree (e.g., for WFFM they live here `/sitecore/System/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Actions/Save Actions` or `/sitecore/System/Settings/Forms/Submit Actions` for the new Sitecore Forms), select the item, select `Navigate` in the ribbon, and select `Links` to get a full list of items that reference that Save Action.

Edit:
If you find no references, it's a good idea to rebuild the links database. Here is a blog post outlining how to do that

**[Links Database](http://sitecore-masters.com/en/link-database/)**

If you want to customize the output through powershell since you mentioned wanting to see the paths you can use this blog post to get the relevant API

**[Working with Item References](https://blogs.perficient.com/2020/05/25/sitecore-powershell-6-working-with-item-references/)**

Comment: I clicked directly on the Save Action in question in the tree and did what you said and got this (not helpful, I need names or paths to forms that use it): Items that refer to the selected item:
None
Items that the selected item refer to:
$name - [/sitecore/templates/Branches/Web Forms for Marketers/Save Action/$name]
Submit Action - [/sitecore/templates/Web Forms for Marketers/Actions/Submit Action]

Comment: Try rebuilding `sitecore_master_index` and then check again

Comment: @kyleb go to `/sitecore/shell` to access the Desktop view. Click the Sitecore button on bottom left, click `Control Panel`, hit `Rebuild Links Database`, select Master, and try the Navigate-Links steps again. If you have any references they would be in the former section - `Items that refer to the selected item`. If you click on them you would be redirected to them and you can grab the path from there.

Comment: Didn't work after I reindexed. Still same result. And if I click on the submit action one it doesn't list anything useful either when i do Navigate -> Links